# How can I log errors from uswgi + flask app?

Tags: flask, uwsgi, wsgi

I'm new to wsgi and flask and want to check the logs. However I cannot print the logs to a file. I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) to set up my project. I would like to log things like print statements in python and errors that occue.

this is my config for usgwi server.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = false
processes = 1

socket = myproject.sock
socket = stats.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

plugins-dir = /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins
plugins = logfile


logger = file:logs.log
logger-req = file:requests.log
stats = myproject.sock
```

logs.log and requests.log never get filled (master=false and process=1 because i am using tensorflow in the app)

then i have the wsgi.py

```
from main import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

then the flask app main.py

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/www')

@app.route('/')
def send_index():
    print("I want to print this to logs")
    x = 1 / 0 # I would like this to throw a ZeroDivisionError and send it to logs
    return send_from_directory('www', 'index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: where is [app logger](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/logging/)?

Comment: thanks for this tip!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use logging within the app using the 'logging' package. A few quick hints:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='record.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format=f'%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s')
```

Should be called in main.py after your app is declared.
You may also use:

```
current_app.logger.info("Your message here")
```

to log specific events.

Comment: Thank you this solved it for me. I would upvote but don't have enough rep yet! :)

Comment: @NiklasD. a small gift from me ;)